# Shared hosting, add library path (similar to ZEND)

Tags: php, zend-framework, shared-hosting, set-include-path

I am actually installing google API Library.
I can't change php.ini, so I am trying to use `set_include_path()`

```
$clientLibraryPath = "/library/Zend";
$old = get_include_path();                       // = .:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php
$new = dirname(__FILE__) .$clientLibraryPath;    // = /home/bastienc/www/perso/Education/Youtube_Bundle/library/Zend

set_include_path($old . PATH_SEPARATOR . $new);
```

I put my library folder in `/library`.
How can I access it ?

I am using Zend GData installation checker script from here : http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/demos/Zend/Gdata/InstallationChecker.php

and it gives me that error

```
Exception thrown trying to access Zend/Loader.php using 'use_include_path' = true. Make sure you include Zend Framework in your include_path which currently contains: .:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php:/home/bastienc/www/perso/Education/Youtube_Bundle/library/Zend
```

[Here is my tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYGdZ.jpg)

Comment: You want the library folder on your include path, not the Zend folder within it. `$clientLibraryPath = "/library";`

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I already tried with only /library but I still have the same error